# TFS help - Backlog,burncharts, velocity, and raising questions in TFS

Tags: workflow, bug-tracking

Can I have guidence for TFS 2010 for the following areas:

What is the correct use of tfs and the properties that are exposed for each backlog item and task for recording of effort so that we report on progress using the burndown charts and can assess velocity.

It is not obvious to us what is the appropriate workflow for raising questions about functionality against tasks / user stories so that the person who needs to answer them can easily find those tasks / stories that have outstanding questions. And for when the question is answered how the person(s) who need to know the answer are alerted that the answer is there. Maybe tfs is not the right place to do this and we should be manually doing this?

Comment: Which process template are you using? That will change some of the answers around how to get your data to show in your reports and what fields you should use for collaboration as they are often specific to certain work item types.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you customized something, the report features you are asking about will light up in the reports if you use the field in the Task work item named Remaining Work - update it regularly - daily if possible.

The database most of the default reports use (Tfs_Analysis) gets updated every 2 hours by default.  Some of the reports only show a daily roll-up so depending on what you are looking for you might not see changes until the day after.

As for your 2nd question about how to communicate about missing information in user stories, etc.. you should read the Process Guidance for the template that was used to create your Team Project.  I'm guessing you are using the MSF Agile 5.0 template, so do a search for that and "Process Guidance."  The Process Guidance is basically the instructions for how to use the TFS work items and reports, etc...  It can be found online (on MSDN) or by right-clicking on your team project in Team Explorer and choosing Process Guidance from the context menu. I'm answering this from my phone but can include a link to it later if you find this helpful.